# Python: Kill the parent process after creating child processes

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a polling job written in Python that is executed every 15 minutes to check if the status of an entry in the job table is `True`. If the status is true then I need to take the values from the table and pass them as arguments to another script that executes something.

I am creating the child processes using `Process` in Python's `Multiprocessing` module but I am unable to exit the polling job(parent script) after starting these processes. The polling job keeps waiting until the children complete even if there is a `sys.exit()` written after creating the children.

```
#pollingjob.py
import sys
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from secondscript import secondscriptfunction

def createParallelBatches(a,b,c):
    for i in [1,2,3]:
        p1 = Process(target=secondscriptfunction,args=(a,b,c)).start()
    sys.exit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    # Check the table for *status=True* rows
    # If such rows exit call CreateParallelBatches with the column values
```

What I am failing to understand is that, why `sys.exit()` won't let me exit the program leaving the spawned processes as orphans. I tried `subprocess` module but it also behaves in the same way. I don't want the parent process waiting on its children to complete. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which OS are you using, if it's Linux then I have a solution using an extra sh command when you launch your process. I'm not familiar with windows scripts

Comment: It is Linux. Not Windows

Answer (score 0):

you need to launch an independent sub process externally. This is one way to do it :

1. put the secondscriptfunction into one executable python file

File `runscript.py`

```
import sys
from secondscript import secondscriptfunction
if __name__=='__main__':
        secondscriptfunction(sys.argv[1:]) #passing arguments to the func
```

2. use subprocess.popen in your script:

File `pollingjob.py`

```
import subprocess
import shlex
def createParallelBatches(a,b,c):
    for i in [1,2,3]:
       command = "python runscript.py %s %s %s "%(a,b,c)
       cmd_args = shlex.split(command)
       subprocess.Popen(cmd_args)
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the process object from the _children set of the current process object, the the parent process will exit immediately.

Theh multiprocessing module manages child processes in a private set and join them when the current process exits. You can remove children from the set if you don't care of them.

```
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc_main)
            multiprocessing.current_process()._children.discard(process)
            exit(0)
```